# beveling edge geometry with merged single vertex problem

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I want to make geometry like in images but blender bevel command is primitive unlike CAD programs and I have an issue about it. I want to bevel blue edges but it end up with unwanted results at single vertex section.

My long way process is given in pictures. To achive final result, every vertex should connect one by one. It is unefficient and not parametric. Is there a way doing it quickly?
[image: face orientations]
[image: process]

Here unwanted result and settings.

[image: unwanted result]
[image: bevel modifier settings]

Here there is referance image while I model.

[image: Referance models]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bevel command CTRL+B on single or multiple edges.
This will be a destructive workflow, but it should solve the problem.
Another way would be to use SUBD Modelling: Sub D Modifier and creases with CTRL+R.